# Storage for Eldritch Horror

Tags: storage, eldritch-horror

Is there an optimal strategy for storing Eldritch Horror cards and tokens so that game play is facilitated.

I am not looking for answers that including "zip bags" and other things to keep the game element safer while is storage. Although, a strategy that works well for both cases will clearly be superior to one that only works for game play.

I am not limiting this to commercial solutions. I am quiet happy to build your custom made solution if you release the specification/plans of course!  Although, it it requires a 3D printer, more power to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked into foam core?

[There](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3028822#item3028822)
[image]
[are](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3051897#item3051897)
[image]
[a lot](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3063393#item3063393)
[image]
[of solutions](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3077727#item3077727)
[image]
[available](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3154213#item3154213)
[image]
[on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/115468/item/3228589#item3228589)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what you want to hear, but I actually built a wooden box for this because there was nothing on the market I could find that would do the job.

It wasn't massively complex - create partitions that could hold decks of cards on their sides, and squarer partitions for counters, dice and the like. There's an elastic strap in the lid for the board.

That way you can open the box, set out the board and everything you need is accessible right away.

The only commercial thing I can think of that might help is a brochure storage rack, the sort you see in shops and libraries. But the compartments are probably too large to be ideal. Here's a selection grabbed at random from Google:

http://www.staples.com/Literature-Holders-Desktop/cat_CL142157

A part of me thinks FFG is deliberately putting out games with baked-in storage problems just so they can sell us custom boxes further down the line. X-Wing, I'm looking at you.

Comment: +1, who said anything about me not building my own thanks to your super plans!!! ^_~  Question edited.

Comment: Cheaper solution? Plano tacklebox with adjustable partitions. It isn't hard to find the right size to fit all the components.

Comment: @generalcrispy I've never found one with the right sized slots for small card decks that you can draw right out of the box. If you can tell me where I can get them, I'm all ears.

Comment: Walmart has plenty of them, and a good selection in the sporting good section. I'd recommend the Pro-latch 1715 or models like it.

Comment: @generalcrispy Being in the UK, I lack access to a Walmart. But hopefully your comment will point others in the right direction. Curse your transatlantic access to a wider range of hardware storage products! ;)

Comment: I'll say. You might be able to find them on Amazon.