# What's the best way to store Eldritch Horror with all the expansions

Tags: eldritch-horror

I was wondering what the best method of storing Eldritch Horror including all the expansions that also allows for a faster set-up time. Thanks!

Comment: "Best"?, might that not be a matter of opinion?

Comment: [Duplicate of Storage for Eldritch Horror](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/16651/5318)